# Do not Show Edit Form on Clicking Edit Button in Radgrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using custom Form for adding/Updating my records from RadGrid. I have a Column in RadGrid as:

```
   <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Edit" ButtonType="ImageButton"  UniqueName="myEditColumn">
                        </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
```

I want to stick with using this column for my Edit Command but clicking this button open Built it Edit Form of Radgrid. I don't want to open that EditForm by clicking this column. 
I don't want to use some other approach for putting custom image for this. Instead I must have to use build In Edit column of RadGrid as I posted that in Code.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this sample that demonstrates custom edit forms with the RadGrid:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/manager/dynamicajaxsettings/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid